# Ingress in AKS does not have any active Endpoint

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster. I install ingress with the command

```
helm upgrade --install --create-namespace ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=$IngressIP --namespace nginx-ingress --atomic
```

According to schedule I create a cluster, run tests and delete. I deploy the application using Helm charts. But since yesterday it stopped working. Although before half a year it worked without interruptions. For some reason I got errors in the nginx logs

```
Service "test-apis/test-load-api" does not have any active Endpoint.
```

All labels are present. And I can't understand what changed a day ago in ingress or AKS , what stopped working. Could you please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to several reason. You can try with below solution.

- in my application definition you might using `name` as my selector, Whereas in my service I was using `app`.After updating my service to use `app`.
- Another situation when it may happen is when ingress class of the ingress controller does not match ingress class in the ingress resource manifest used for your services.
- In our case, this was caused by having the ingress resource definition on a different namespace then the services.

You can refer this [***Stack thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028596/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-not-finding-service-endpoint) to troubleshoot your issue.

Also this might be a bug with newer version of `nginx-ingress-controller`. You can also go through the troubleshooting steps given in the [***github***](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/250) discussion might works for you if still not please report a bug in github for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is permission
Check the permissions on the SA that u r running the pipeline with